# Crashlytics beta: How to download previous versions

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I know that you can download earlier versions of your app distributed through Crashlytics Beta via the Crashlytics Beta iOS app.

However, the Crashlytics Beta app does NOT appear anywhere on my home screen even after downloading my app.

How do I get the Crashlytics Beta app to show up on my home screen?